# libGDX with Kotlin error "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt.idea.KaptModelBuilderService"

Tags: libgdx, kotlin

I'm trying to create libGDX with Kotlin option. After creating a project with libGDX, opening it with Android Studio. IDE give the error below:

> Error:Could not initialize class 
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt.idea.KaptModelBuilderService

What wrong with my project? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error due to Version mismatch between `Kotlin plugin` and `Gradle`.

Here is the similar [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20967) tracked at JetBrains issue tracker, also there is [post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000666624-Cannot-sync-Gradle-Kotlin-project-with-2017-3-Public-Preview) for the same issue.

---

Try to disable Kotlin plugin and update to latest version.

I've no issue while using Kotlin in Android Studio 3.0.1.

I'm using :

- Gradle version `3.3`
- Kotlin plugin version `1.2.10-release-studio3.0-1`
- Kotlin version `1.2.10`
- Android-gradle-plugin version `2.3.3`
- LibGDX `1.9.8`